# php replace array value with another array value that is out of order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How would you write a sorting routine in PHP that would replace the values of an array's keys, with another array's key value's if the former array's key value's are out of order.

```
$array1 = ['section2', 'section3', 'section1'];
$array2 = ['content for section1', 'content for section2', 'content section3'];
```

How could I replace the values of `$array1` with the corrosponding content in `$array2`?

So I guess what I'm asking is how can I make `$array1` display the following....

```
content for section2
content for section3
content for section1
```

in that order....

Comment: check this manuals http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: What relation between two array ? content for section2 is a sample value or always end with word `section2` ?

Comment: If there is not any relationship between two array orders your question hasn't any solution

Comment: Somewhere logical error hidden. Is this an actual code? What if content for `section1` has a link or reference for `section2`? Why you don't want to have the second array like this: `$array2 = ['section1'=>'content for section1', 'section2'=>'content for section2', ... etc]` ? You need to have strong relationship between this two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop both arrays and check if the value of `$array1` exists while looping `$array2`, if so, change the value of `$array1` to the `$array2` value based on the `key`, so you can keep the order, i.e.:

```
$array1 = ['section2', 'section3', 'section1'];
$array2 = ['content for section1', 'content for section2', 'content for section3'];

foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    foreach($array2 as $key2 => $value2){
        if(preg_match("/$value/", $value2)){
            $array1[$key] = $value2;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array1);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => content for section2
    [1] => content for section3
    [2] => content for section1
)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ezZ0Ou)

Comment: I think that 1. `$key2` should not be declared and 2. there should be a `break` in the inner loop.